# .net core how to access shared folder on server outside project

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm building a small app and want to access files (images) from a directory outside the project but on the same server the app will be running.

How can I access the directory I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this in Startup.cs inside Configure:

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(env.ContentRootPath + "/Albums"),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/Albums"),
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
});
```

And from Model that should be using it:

```
Initialize(_environment.WebRootPath + "/Albums");
```